# Use index of first and second repeated index in list

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, split

There are lots of similar posts out there, but I could not find something that directly matched, or resulted in a solution to, the issue I am dealing with.

I want to use the second instance of a repeated index contained in a list as the index of another list. When the function is executed, I want all numbers from the start of the list up to the first `'\*'` to print after Code1, all numbers between the first `'\*'` and the second `'\*'` to print after Code2, and then all numbers following the second `'\*'` until the end of the list to print after Code3. Example data for `digit` would be `"['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '\*', '6', '\*', '7', '8', '9', '10', '1']"`.

In other words, I want the code below to print , assuming those digits exist, `User Code: 12345, Pass Code: 6, Pin Code: 789101`, all in one line.

```
print_string += 'User Code: {} '.format(''.join(str(dig) for dig in digit[:digit.index('*')])) + \
                        'Pass Code: {} '.format(''.join(str(dig) for dig in digit[digit.index('*'):digit.index('*')])) + \
                        'Pin Code: {} '.format(''.join(str(dig) for dig in digit[digit.index('*'):]))
print(print_string)
```

Essentially, I would like to call the first asterisk as the right index for User Code, the first asterisk as the left index and the second asterisk as the right index for Pass Code, and the second asterisk as the left index for Pin Code.

I just cannot figure out how make it look for sequential asterisks. If there is a simpler way to execute this, please let me know!

Comment: Join all of the items in the list and then use `split('\*')`

Comment: You have `"['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '\*',...` but say you want `User Code: 1234` then `Pass Code: 5...` - have I misunderstood, or did you put the * in the wrong place in the list (in the string)?

Comment: @doctorlove I accidentally copied the wrong data set - I did put the \* in the wrong place. I will edit it now. Thanks for the good eye.

Answer (score 0):

Given,

```
L = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '\*', '6', '\*', '7', '8', '9', '10', '1']
```

Then

```
str.join('', L)
```

will form a string

```
'12345\\*6\\*789101'
```

which you can split into the three parts

```
parts = str.join('', L).split('\*')
```

and then pull out what you need

```
user_code = parts[0]
pass_code = parts[1]
pin = parts[2]
```

If you have actually got all the digits in a list like shape ina string,

```
"['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '\*', '6', '\*', '7', '8', '9', '10', '1']"
```

it might be worth just having them as a list, then you can use the join/split method above.